# Закрытие всплывающего окна через клик по тегу

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

такая ситуация. Имеется код на:

*HTML*:

```
  <div class="chat_block">
    <img src="images/Chat.svg">
  </div>

  <form class="chat_popup_form">
    <h4 class="close_chat_window">Закрити</h4>
    <div class="message_block">
      <label class="label_message">
        <textarea type="text" name="message"></textarea>
        <div class="label_of_message">
          Сообщение
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="message_submit">Написать</button>
  </form>
```

*JavaScript*:

```
let chatPopupOpen = document.querySelectorAll(".chat_block");
let chatPopupForm = document.querySelector(".chat_popup_form");
let closeChatButton = document.querySelector(".close_chat_window");
let aaablya = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

chatPopupOpen.forEach((chatButton) => {
  chatButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    chatPopupForm.classList.add("active_chat_form");
  });
});
closeChatButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
});

document.addEventListener("click", (closeChat) => {
  if (closeChat.target === aaablya) {
    chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
  }
});
```

Не думаю, что *CSS* имеет большое влияние на проблему + стилей, мешающих её решению, у меня в файле точно нет

***Сама проблема***: хочу реализовать закрывание модального окна через клик по **любому** тегу `<a>` (в моём случае) на странице (вне зависимости от расположения тега в DOM-дереве).

Например пользователь открыл чат и у него есть 2 способа закрытия чата: через саму кнопку closeChatButton и через клик по любой ссылке **(тегу `<a>`)** в документе (смысла от диалогового окна не будет, если пользователь решит совершить другое действие, не совершив закрытие чат-окна)

`document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, `document.querySelector("a")` и `document.querySelectorAll("a")` не работают вообще, скорее всего я неверно подтягиваю теги, потому прошу о помощи. Буду благодарен за совет/решение, т.к. вообще не понимаю, что не так

Comment: getElementsByTagName возвращает html коллекцию и вы её сравниваете с эл-том?

Comment: "сравниваете с эл-том" - 

можете объяснить, что значит это? Не совсем понимаю, если имеете ввиду, что через ```getElementsByTagName``` не достучаться к нужным тегам, то я пробовал и через ```querySelector``` (```All``` в том числе) и тоже не работает, пока более глубоко разбираюсь в структуре DOM и решения пока не нахожу

Comment: Если вы о том, что в HTML коде нет запрашиваемого тега - это лишь непосредственно нативная часть той функции, которую я пробую так сказать склепать. Во всём документе в разных местах есть запрашиваемые теги, у меня вопрос - как к каждому из них можно одновременно достучаться и дальше использовать

Comment: Я вот об этом 'if (closeChat.target === aaablya) {' - добавьте перед условием вывод в консоль `console.log(closeChat.target, aaablya)` и посмотрите что вы сравниваете. *моргните, если поняли

Comment: Так, дошло, что имеете ввиду, не зря стебанулись с меня. Спасибо за наводку. Выводиться коллекция, но застопорился на ней, её перебором и использованием. Если можете помочь, за что буду признателен, есть таков код:

```let aaa = document.getElementsByTagName("a");//Вытягиваю коллекцию

let mmm;

//Цикл для пересчёта элементов коллекции и записи в пустую переменную mmm
for (let r = 0; r < aaa.length; r++) {
  mmm += aaa[r];
};

document.addEventListener("click", (closeChat) => {
  if (closeChat.target === mmm) {
    chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
  }
});```

Comment: Также работает без цикла через метод ```aaa.item()```, но можно записать только одно число в аргумент и я так понимаю, что всё равно нужен цикл, который количество элементов коллекции записывает в пустую переменную и эту переменную нужно вписать как аргумент в метод ```aaa.item()```. Пробую добавлять ```let ttt = aaa.item(mmm);``` и к переменной ```ttt``` крепить обработчик событий - не работает

Comment: Можете чуток опять стебануться))

Comment: Зародился в голове ещё вариант реализации: как я увидел между ```getElementsByTagName``` и, например, ```getElementsByClassName``` есть разница: 1-ый выводит список элементов как объект, второй - элемент с классом как объект. 
Можно реализовать функцию посредством добавления классов к каждому тегу ```<a>```.
Опять же, если можете дать наводку и, возможно, вспомнить теорию для себя - дайте, пожалуйста)

Comment: Вы что-то не туда свернули) У вас есть вариант готовый это добавление. Только там вы перебирали массив chatPopupOpen, а тут надо перебирать это - `let aaa = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Comment: Проблема в том, что я перебираю коллекцию ```document.getElementsByTagName("a")``` циклом, но у меня не получается прикрепить обработчик событий на каждый элемент из цикла, а получается, что я всё равно прикрепляю его на целый список вместо отдельного элемента в этом списке и функция не работает. Плюс я понял, что опростоволосился: ```getElementsByClassName``` и ```document.getElementsByTagName``` оба выводят коллекцию, а не элемент, как я подумал. Поэтому через добавление класса у меня тоже ничего не выходит.

Comment: Пример - 
```let tagA = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(let i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++ ){
  tagA[i].classList.add('a');
}

let classA = document.getElementsByClassName(".a");

document.addEventListener("click", (closeChat) => {
  if (closeChat.target === classA) {
    chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
  }
});```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach(el => { el.addEventListener("click", evt => chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form") ) }`

Comment: Так, огромадная благодарность Вам, senior, так просто то было, стыдно стало. Внесу небольшие правки, по крайней мере у меня так: метод forEach не работает с коллекциями, только с массивами, потому коллекцию предварительно надо перевести в массив
```
let aaaArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
aaaArray.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
  });
});
``` 

Если смолчали, чтоб я сам подумал - моё почтение Вам, лучше разобрался в теории

Comment: просто на querySelectorAll завтыкал поменять, вот почему лучше не копировать

Comment: Ничего, все равно большая Вам благодарность за решение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

И так, в комментариях InDevX помог решить такую банальную, но проблему, за что ему благодарность. Код решения:

```
//вытягиваем теги из документа и переводим коллекцию с ними в массив
let aaaArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
/*методом forEach вызываем каждый элемент массива 
и вешаем на каждый элемент обработчик событий*/
aaaArray.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    chatPopupForm.classList.remove("active_chat_form");
  });
});
```